# Are OPTION=true and OPTION=1 equivalent when passing options to a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a large make file with a line that says "ifeq ($(OPTION),1)....", which means that if I say "make OPTION=1 target" the conditional code will be executed. Is the meaning of '1' and 'true' overloaded, like in some languages? Specifically, the will conditional code also be executed if I do "make OPTION=true target"? Or would I need to change the conditional to ""ifeq ($(OPTION),true)...." to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent.

`make` just works with text and the condition compares the text "1" to "1" which is true, or "true" to "1" which is false.

You can demonstrate this easily with a simple makefile:

```
ifeq ($(OPTION),1)
$(info OPTION == 1)
endif
ifeq ($(OPTION),true)
$(info OPTION == true)
endif

.PHONY: all
all:
```

Then run it with different values for the variable:

```
$ make 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
$ make OPTION=1
OPTION == 1
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
$ make OPTION=true
OPTION == true
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```